# How to Query totals hours worked in a week based always on the same starting day

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to do a getdate() and then add all hours together from a Sunday to getdate(). I have a totals hrs worked based on an ID  for each date in my database. - I was able to use this query and it gave me what I needed

```
;WITH empworkhours AS
 (
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY
            ,   -(DATEPART(dw, datein) )
            ,   datein) AS week_start
    ,   DATEADD(DAY
            ,   7 - (DATEPART(dw, datein))
            ,   datein) AS week_end
    ,   employeeid
    ,   TotalTime
FROM    Data_TimeCards_T where (datein between DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7,-1)     and  DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 5)) and PunchType IN ('C','E')
)
SELECT      DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7,-1) AS week_start
    ,   DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 5) AS Week_end
    ,   employeeid
    ,   SUM(TotalTime) total_hrs_per_week
FROM        empworkhours
GROUP BY    week_start
    ,   week_end
    ,   employeeid;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you want the [ADDDATE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate). This question is really difficult to answer without any other specifics, but take a look at that link as well as the other functions in that article and you may find what you're looking for.

If not, please post what a sample database table with your expected output and any queries you've tried so far and I can help you work them into a solution.

Comment: While clicking on your link i found something that pointed me in the right direction. - Thank you

Comment: Odd that the posted link helped. The code you posted is sql server and the link posted is mysql. >.<

Comment: Glad that was useful. I was kinda going on a limb haha.

Comment: I ended up searching for a similar function in MSSQL and stumbled on to what I needed. Guess I just needed a starting point.

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes a push in the right direction is better than being lead directly to the solution. You can learn more, and even stumble upon more useful things. I reference that article a lot for date related functions, definitely worth it to bookmark in the future. (And it's gotten me rep on Stack, because I've answered two different questions with it now ;P)